# Oracle query for REGEX_LIKE for list of strings

Tags: plsql

am new to regex, I need the following to 
a sql query to extract rows with columns to match any or all 4 strings but nothing beyond those 4 strings

e.g

row1 field has: abc, def, ghi, xyz

row2 field has: abc, ghi, xyz

row3 field has: ghi; abc,

row4 field has: poi; iop

lets say we need all with value "xyz" and/or "abc" and/or "ghi"

it should only return row2 and row3

I tried
select * from emp where REGEX_LIKE(empname, '. * (abc|ghi|xyz).*$')

but with little luck, it return all the above rows since am not able to negate those with additional patters. 
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
select * from emp where REGEXP_LIKE(empname, '^[(abc|ghi|xyz) ,;]+$');
```

Comment: Thanks gurwinder, this is close, however am still getting rows with subelements of patterns abc, ghi xyz:

Comment: This results rows with subelements of patterns abc, ghi xyz: e.g           with demo as
     ( select 'abc, def, ghi, xyz' as demo1 from dual union all
       select 'abc, ghi, xyz' from dual union all
       select 'ghi, abc,' from dual union all
       select 'ghi, c, abc,' from dual union all
       select 'abc, gh, xyz' from dual union all
       select 'poi, iop' from dual )
       select * from demo1 where REGEXP_LIKE(csv, '^[(abc|ghi|xyz) ,;]+$');
       result: abc, ghi, xyz and ghi, abc,  and ghi, c, abc and abc, gh, xyz

Answer (score 0):

How about `(\A|\W)(abc|ghi|xyz)(\Z|\W)`, as in:

```
with demo as
     ( select 'abc, def, ghi, xyz' as csv from dual union all
       select 'abc, ghi, xyz' from dual union all
       select 'ghi; abc,' from dual union all
       select 'poi; iop' from dual )
select csv
     , case
           when regexp_like(csv,'(\A|\W)(abc|ghi|xyz)(\Z|\W)')
               then 'Y'
           end as matched
from   demo;
```

I've used `\W` (any nonword character) as the delimiter. You could be more specific and use `[,; ]` if you only want the delimiters you have in the sample.

**Edit:** just reread your question and noticed you said it should only match rows 2 and 3, but my pattern also matches row 1. I must be missing something because I'm not sure why *all with value "xyz" and/or "abc" and/or "ghi"* shouldn't match `'abc, def, ghi, xyz'`. Is it because that has more than one matched pattern in it?

Comment: Hi William, thanks for the reply. 
The reason Row1 should not match is because it has more elements ('def')in the set than we need (which is only 'abc', 'ghi', 'xyz'). Basically am looking for rows which only has **one, more or all** elements of {**abc, ghi, xyz**} only and ignore all rows which has any other element **irrespective** of the fact that wether it has one of our or not. Again thanks a lot for all the help.